# Why does the water in a bucket stay even when swung around in circular motion?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, reference-frames, centripetal-force, free-body-diagram, centrifugal-force

What are the force that act on the water and which force is responsible to keep the water from falling out?

Answer (score 1):

The 'swinging in a circle' creates a centripetal force that accelerates all water away from the center of the circle, with the force increasing with the distance from the center.

The result will be that the water will orient so it is maximally distant from the center of the rotation. Hindered by the bucket from simply flying away, the resulting surface will form a piece of a sphere (again centered on the center of rotation, so a rather large sphere). Typically, that is not visible to the naked eye, so it *appears* flat; but it has an indention in the middle and curvarture. For a large bucket and near enough to rotation center, you could see it.

Comment: Calling a force a centripetal force, is just pointing out that there is a force pointing towards the center of the circle. It doesn't tell you what the force is. The force is from the bucket, the bucket deforms slightly (strain) and this results in a stress to the bucket which forces it to exert a pressure on the water next to it. And each layer of water feels different pressure from the two sides so that the difference is enough to have a net force exactly enough for its mass to make it accelerate inwards enough to maintain the circular motion.

Comment: I am aware of that, @Timaeus, I was trying to give a highschool-level answer, not a college or PhD-grade answer. Of course, the OP might have looked for one or the other, I don't know, then he will not accept my answer

Comment: No one else can answer now. And the question literally asked which force, and it's pressure: the pressure difference from the two sides of each layer.

Comment: ?? Why not? Anyone can still answer? Try it.

Comment: Earlier I was merely suggesting ways to improve your answer by telling you how to answer the actual questions asked. I wasn't trying to school you. But now you are just wrong. The question is closed and no one else can answer it. So yours will be the only answer, even though you didn't answer the question. It's like if someone asked what force makes things fall and you said it was a downwards pointing force. The correct answer would be gravity, and yes gravity points downwards. The answer here is pressure and yes all the pressure's net force points towards the center.

Comment: I did not see it was closed, and it wasn't closed because of my answer (and not by me). If I delete my answer, or never made it, it would be still closed. - but feel free to edit my answer to improve it.